# How to reduce the amount of fields for _joinData in Cake 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, contains

## Situation

Using `Cake 3.2.4`

I have a `EventTicketSales` table

that

```
  $this->belongsToMany('Approvings', [
        'className' => 'Contacts',
        'joinTable' => 'event_ticket_sales_approvings',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'contact_id',
        'saveStrategy' => 'replace',
    ]);
```

When I do a pagination like this:

```
       $this->paginate['contain'] = [
            'Approvings' => function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
                return $query->select([
                    'Approvings.id',
                    'Approvings.name',
                    'Approvings.company',
                    'EventTicketSalesApprovings.event_ticket_sale_id'
                ]);
            }
        ];
        $this->paginate['fields'] = [
            'EventTicketSales.id', 'EventTicketSales.event_id', 'EventTicketSales.billing_amount_in_sgd', 
            'EventTicketSales.payment_terms', 'EventTicketSales.invoice_number', 
            'EventTicketSales.due_date',
        ];
```

I get the following data:

```
id: "06f39ba3-9a17-47c6-9374-24b49fb64665",
event_id: 7,
billing_amount_in_sgd: 7680.03,
payment_terms: "45 days",
invoice_number: "9191",
due_date: "2016-03-05T00:00:00+0800",
approvings: [
    {
        id: 63,
        name: "Jaime Jen",
        company: "Apple Company",
        _joinData: {
            contact_id: 63,
            id: 335,
            event_ticket_sale_id: "06f39ba3-9a17-47c6-9374-24b49fb64665",
            created: "2016-01-20T13:43:44+0800",
            modified: "2016-01-20T13:43:44+0800"
        }
    }
]
```

## What I want

I would like to also control the amount of data I retrieve from `_joinData`

Ideally I want as few fields from _joinData as I can possibly retrieve.

```
id: "06f39ba3-9a17-47c6-9374-24b49fb64665",
event_id: 7,
billing_amount_in_sgd: 7680.03,
payment_terms: "45 days",
invoice_number: "9191",
due_date: "2016-03-05T00:00:00+0800",
approvings: [
    {
        id: 63,
        name: "Jaime Jen",
        company: "Apple Company",
        _joinData: {
            id: 335,
            contact_id: 63,
            event_ticket_sale_id: "06f39ba3-9a17-47c6-9374-24b49fb64665",
        }
    }
]
```

I actually don't even need the _joinData if I can help it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could for example iterate the collection and remove the properties that you're not interested in, something like:

```
$eventTicketSales->map(function ($row) {
    foreach ($row['approvings'] as &$approving) {
        unset($approving['_joinData']);
    }

    return $row;
});
```

Which could also be done in a result formatter of a query object:

```
$query->formatResults(function (\Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface $results) {
    return $results->map(function ($row) {
        foreach ($row['approvings'] as &$approving) {
            unset($approving['_joinData']);
        }

        return $row;
    });
});
```

Or, since you seem to want to apply this in JSON representations, you could mark the `_joinData` property of the `Approving` entity as hidden, given that you'd generally want to ditch that property when converting entities to arrays or JSON:

```
class Approving extends Entity {
    // ...

    protected $_hidden = [
        '_joinData'
    ];

    // ...
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Collections](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Queries Are Collection Objects](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#queries-are-collection-objects)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Adding Calculated Fields](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-calculated-fields)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Entities > Converting to Arrays/JSON > Hiding Properties](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#hiding-properties)**

Comment: When I tried to do a $this->log($row).. I saw that there is no _joinData. There was a event_ticket_sales_approvings. I unset ($row->event_ticket_sales_approvings). I got jsonSerialize error.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that the associations result injector is being applied _after_ the query is being evaluated. I've updated my answer. @KimStacks

Comment: I prefer the `protected $_hidden = ` way. Thanks

Comment: For associated model with belongsToMany does not work

Comment: @giuseppe The question _is_ about `belongsToMany`, and the examples can generally be applied/adapted to any type of associated data. If you have any problems you need to be a little more specific as to what exactly you're doing, and what exactly is happening. You may want open a new question for that, where you can add example code and elaborate on the problem.

Comment: @ndm here you are https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59118525/how-to-hide-fields-in-associated-data-cakephp-3-x

Comment: @giuseppe Looks like you're disabling hydration, so you're working with arrays (passed by value) instead of entities (objects passed by reference), hence changes to the data are not being preserved. I've updated the example to use `map()` and force reference usage, so that it works with non-hydrated results too.